# File.ReadAllLines prepends executable path to provided path

Tags: c#, file, io, path, file-read

I've come across a very strange error. So strange even that it seems like a bug to me, but what do I know.

I use the File.ReadAllLines(path) method in my code, like so:

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

So far so simple. The path I read is on my C drive, so its in the following format: *C:\Folder\Folder\File.txt*

[Putting a break-point at the above line and hovering over the path variable shows the correct path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJPsM.png)

Here is where it gets strange. If I actually run this code I get an IOException, which informs me of an invalid path. The path it shows seems to be the path of my applications executable location + the path I passed to the method.

> 'C:\Users\kingv\Projects\C#\AUDS\Bsp2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\‪C:\Users\kingv\Projects\C#\AUDS\data\asc1k.txt

This error also occurs when using the File.ReadAllText method.

Whats weirder is that this seems to be a project specific issue. I have two projects in this solution. Except for very few differences, they have the exact same code, and the code relevant to my issue is exactly the same (The declaration and reading of the path)

I have never had problems with the File.ReadAllLines method before. Anybody got a clue what is going on here?

Comment: I am facing now the same problem as I passed a file path string which is not on my local machine but on a shared folder on a LAN. It starts with "//192.168 ", do I have to rewrite it without double slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproduced your problem, but only was able to do so by copying the path written by the error message in your question.

Your path has an illegal character at the beginning, therefore it is not considered as an absolute, rooted path, instead, considered as a relative path.

You need to revise the source of the path, or if it is a literal just delete `"C:\` part and write it again.

You can see this by:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(path)
```

As far as I can see, it is Unicode #8234 which is something like this:

[image]

This can also be seen when checking the element content with developer tools of chrome:

[image]

Comment: I got the source string from the files properties window. Apparently I copied some illegal character there. Replacing only the start did not help, however rewriting the entire path did fix the problem. Thank you very much, really interesting problem.